# How can I view files in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I have just started learning about AWS. I am following along a tutorial and I have created a `hello.txt` file in EC2 using PuTTY on Windows. I wanted to know where I can see all the files listed in the EC2 instance on a GUI. I believe they are not stored locally on my computer; but I cannot find them on the AWS console either? Thank you.

PuTTY console screenshot
[image: PuTTY console screenshot]

Comment: Use WinSCP for "gui" like access to your files on the instance.

Comment: They are in the ec2 and I am afraid you won't be able to see those in GUI(in your EC2). You can do an `ls` when you login to your EC2 via putty. There you will see all the files you have created. I would suggest to do a linux course first as you are lacking the very basics of it. I would suggest starting https://www.netacad.com/courses/os-it/ndg-linux-essentials this course. It will take you few days and then you will be able to continue with aws.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know where I can see all the files listed in the EC2 instance on a GUI

**Short answer:**

Using a Windows PC to access an AWS EC2 you use PuTTY to navigate the file system. The hello.txt file you created is listed.

To open it you can do a `cat hello.txt`.

**Official Answer:**

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/

The instructions get you to install the MATE desktop environment, a lightweight GUI based on GNOME 2 available as an extra for Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

After some more AWS training, I found out that I can also see the files and folders in my EC2 instance in a "GUI" format using the Fleet Manager in AWS Systems Manager. The Systems Manager Agent must be installed in the EC2 instance and the instance must be given the appropriate permissions using IAM.